# position a div at bottom of page and reposition up according to divs shown Below

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need to position a div at bottom of the page with another div below it on hidden mode, on click the hidden div will appear below the first div and move it up according to the height of the second div.
for example:

```
Div1 (at bottom of page)
Div2 (hidden)
```

on click event:

```
Div1(moves up the same pixel height of the second div)
Div2(shown bellow Div1 at bottom of page)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/c7qarf7e/1)

```
<div id="first" onclick="doStuff()"> <!-- when the first div is clicked, doStuff() will be called -->
    First
</div>
<div id="second">
    Second
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#first {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;         // these two make the div stuck to the bottom of the page
}

#second {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    display:none; // the 2nd div is hidden
}
```

Javascript:

```
function doStuff(){
    var first = document.getElementById('first'); // the first (visible) div
    var second = document.getElementById('second'); // the second (hidden) div

    second.style.display = 'block'; // show the second element
    first.style.bottom = second.offsetHeight + "px";
    // make the bottom attribute of the first div equal to the height of the second,
    // so the distance between the first element and the bottom of the page is
    // just enough space to fit the 2nd div
}
```

Comment: Great! If there's nothing else you need help with, please mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure CSS way of doing it, but beware, if the second `div`'s height is more than the `div` being hovered, your mouse pointer will no longer `hover`

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.one {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.two {
  width: 80px;
  background-color: green;
}

.one:hover+.two {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is one working example -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.one').click(function(){
    $('.two').toggle(function(){
      $(this).height(80);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.one {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.two {
  width: 80px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Note : Before posting a question, try yourself and post whatever you've tried

Comment: When a question doesn't specifically mention jQuery or doesn't include the jQuery tag, please don't post a jQuery answer.